# getting all pid's from pstree

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get all pid's from `pstree -pA <PID>` output in linux.
I am working in java and thought about doing it with regular expression.
I attached an example output below:

```
eclipse(45905)---java(45906)-+-{java}(45907)  
                             |-{java}(45908)  
                             |-{java}(45909)  
                             |-{java}(45910)  
                             |-{java}(45911)
```

I have written the following code:

```
private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
static List<String> getPidsFromOutput(String output) {
    List<String> $ = Lists.newArrayList();
    List<String> list = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("()\n")).splitToList(output);
    for (String string : list) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            $.add(string);
        }
    }
    return $ ;
}
```

The problem is with processes that their name (ie: the executed file) is a number. it will catch them also and this is buggy.

Do you have any suggestion to fix that? or any other solution?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: list of numbers (pid's)

Comment: you could use `"(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))"`

Comment: `(?<=\\()` - Asserts that the match must be preceded by a `(` symbol and `\\d+` matches one or more digits, `(?=\\))` asserts that the match must be followed by a `)` symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make sure the pid is surrounded by braces, 
in addition your code catches threads as well, to avoid them you should ignore the process that has {} around its name.

```
private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*[^}]\\((\\d+)\\).*");

private Integer pid;
static Set<String> getPidsFromOutput(String output) {
    Set<String> $ = Sets.newHashSet();
    List<String> list = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("\n")).splitToList(output);
    for (String line : list) {
        List<String> perProcess = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("-")).splitToList(line);
        for (String p : perProcess) {
            Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(p);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                $.add(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
    log.info("pids from pstree: " + $);
    return $;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for numbers that are surrounded by braces
`\((\d+)\)`
since process names are surrounded by curly braces it will only get the PID